# How to disable animations in the modeline

Tags: mode-line, web-mode

In the mode-line, web-mode shows an animation:

[image: web-mode animation]

How can it be disabled and where is it set up ?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation or source code for `web-mode`?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't find the source of this functionality. 15k lines of code, I searched for "mode-line", "animate", ' "=" ', " '=' ", "status".

Comment: For now the only solution I found is to remove that list of modes from the mode-line. ```(setq-default mode-line-format (delq 'mode-line-modes mode-line-format))
```

Comment: I also searched for `Web[` and did not find it. That leads me to believe that a minor mode is adding it: do `C-h m` in that buffer and add the list of minor modes to the question - or go through them disabling each one until the animation goes away.

Comment: This might be `lsp-mode` related, I see similar when opening files configured with `lsp-mode` to start.